# Proving $f(x) = \sin(x) + \sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not periodic without using derivation

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Hello I come across a dilemma in my school, I need to prove that $f(x) = \sin(x) + \sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not periodic without using derivation

Comment: By not using a derivation, do you mean not using a derivative? Or if not then what is the  restriction on what can be used in a proof?

Comment: Can you prove that $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not periodic?

Comment: it must be $$f(x+p)=f(x)$$ fort all real $x$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is $T>0$ such that, for all $\alpha\ge 0$,

\begin{align}0=&\sin(\alpha+T)+\sin\sqrt{\alpha+T}-\sin\alpha-\sin\sqrt\alpha=\\=&2\cos\frac{\alpha+T}{2}\sin\frac T2+2\sin\frac{T}{2\sqrt{\alpha+T}+2\sqrt{\alpha}}\cos\frac{\sqrt{\alpha+T}+\sqrt\alpha}{2}\end{align}

Notice that $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}2\sin\frac{T}{2\sqrt{\alpha+T}+2\sqrt{\alpha}}\cos\frac{\sqrt{\alpha+T}+\sqrt\alpha}{2}=0$$

Thus, by hypothesis, it must hold $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}2\cos\frac{\alpha+T}{2}\sin\frac T2=0$$

However, $2\cos\frac{\alpha_k+T}{2}\sin\frac T2=2(-1)^k\sin\frac T2$ for $\alpha_k=2k\pi-T$. Thus, it must hold $$\sin\frac T2=0$$ Id est, $$T=2h\pi$$ for some integer $h>0$. Thus, it must hold $$2\sin\frac{2h\pi}{2\sqrt{\alpha+2h\pi}+2\sqrt{\alpha}}\cos\frac{\sqrt{\alpha+2h\pi}+\sqrt\alpha}{2}=0\qquad\forall\alpha\ge0$$ Evaulate in $\alpha=0$ $$\sin\frac{h\pi}{\sqrt{2h\pi}}\cos\frac{\sqrt{2h\pi}}{2}=\sin\sqrt{\frac{h\pi}2}\cos\sqrt\frac{h\pi}{2}=0$$

But this would mean that $\sqrt\pi$ is the root of some rational number: famously false.

Comment: There's an easier way: $g(x)=f(x+2\pi)-f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{x+2\pi})-\sin(\sqrt{x})$ must be periodic with the same period. But $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=0$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector True. I kind of powered through the problem with the first idea that came to mind at each step.